# SUMPRODUCT where the product is computed from the row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a range AG6:AS38.  It looks like this:

```
      AG   AH   AI  AJ  AK  AL  AM  AN  AO  AP  AQ  AR  AS
   --------------------------------------------------------
6  |  1    A    B   C   D   ...
7  |  2    C    A   D   B   ...
8  |  3    A    W   Q   A   ...
9  |  1    G    A   W   Y   ...
10 |  2   ...
11 |  3
12 |  1
13 |  2
14 |  3
15 |  1
16 |  2
...|  3
```

I need a SUMPRODUCT() or something similar that, for each cell in AH6:AS36 whose value is 'A', will add the corresponding value from AG to the sum.  So basically it counts the number of A's in each row, multiplies the count by AG, and adds that to the sum.  In the above example, if none of the missing cells were A's, it would compute 10.  1+2+3+3+1.

How can I do this?  One idea is to use COUNTIF(AG6:AS6,'A') and put it in AF6 and copy down, then use SUMPRODUCT(AF6:AF38,AG6:AS38), but I can't use a temporary column because A is just an arbitrary example, I need to do this with many different values, not just A.

Essentially the column AG represents the "weight" of items on that row, so it is computing a weighted sum of how popular an item is in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` as long as you have the right syntax, like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((AH6:AS36="A")*AG6:AG36)`

in fact `SUM` also works but you would need to "array enter" if you use SUM, i.e.

`=SUM((AH6:AS36="A")*AG6:AG36)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>